# Python dataframe add a column that selects prev date's data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I am looking to add a column to my current dataframe called **prev_temp**. **Prev_temp** is grouped by location and takes the previous date according to its location's temperature.

```
location   date              temp
NY         2014-02-01        60
NY         2014-02-02        40
LA         2014-01-28        70
LA         2014-02-02        80
```

Here is a sample of how I need the output to be:

```
location   date              temp    prev_temp
NY         2014-02-01        60      null
NY         2014-02-02        40      60
LA         2014-01-28        70      null
LA         2014-02-02        80      70
```

In SQL the condition is

```
lag(temp, 1) over (partition by location order by date) prev_temp
```

However I need to be this in python, so any help greatly appreciated!

The end goal is to compare the value in **temp** column against the value in **prev_temp** column.

An example condition would be to remove all rows where the **prev_temp** decreases in relation to **temp**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [shift with groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = io.String('''location   date              temp
                   NY         2014-02-01        60
                   NY         2014-02-02        40
                   LA         2014-01-28        70
                   LA         2014-02-02        80''')

df = pd.read_csv(txt, sep='\s+')
df['prev_temp'] = df.groupby('location')['temp'].shift(1)
```